# How to avoid circular reference mapping entities in different assemblies/projects on Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Say I have one class in project A:

```
public class ClassOne
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClassTwoId { get; set; }
    public ClassTwo ClassTwo { get; set; }
}
```

And one class in Project B:

```
public class ClassTwo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ClassOne> ClassOnes { get; set;}
}
```

and the Map:

```
var entityConfig = modelBuilder.Entity<ClassOne>();
entityConfig.HasRequired(x => x.ClassTwo)
            .WithMany(x => x.ClassOnes)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ClassTwoId);
```

Since in Entity Framework you need to have a collection of ClassOne in ClassTwo to map it in Code First, how do I map it properly and avoid the circular reference that generates between project A and B?

Comment: You **really** should put all of your entities in one project

Comment: I can't. The project is big and separated in different projects per context. This happens multiple times in it. If I move to the same project I'd have to refactor the whole project and break the design, because there are causes like there is a ClassThree that references ClassTwo, and so on....

Comment: Wondering how you can break something that is impossible to create...

Comment: Exactly. The classes *as you show them* can never be in two separate projects. That has nothing to do with EF. They could if ClassOne, for example, didn't refer to ClassTwo. You can map unidirectional associations with EF alright, I think even when the classes are in two assemblies (never tried).

Comment: I don't agree in having to change my solution structure because of EntityFramework

Comment: It seems that you're not listening. Your solution structure (as you present it here) is impossible. With or without EF.

Comment: Well, it's not impossible. You can do this with NHibernate, which the referenced class doesn't need to have a collection of the class that references.

Comment: As I told you, with EF that's not necessary either.

Comment: @Gert how to do it then in EF? That's what I want and I couldn't find anywhere

Comment: `WithMany` has an overload without parameter, or coming from the other side: `modelBuilder.Entity<ClassTwo>().HasMany(s => s.ClassOnes ).WithRequired()`.

Comment: @Gert, thanks, that's all I wanted, because now I don't need the "public ICollection<ClassOne> ClassOnes { get; set;}" to cause the circular reference

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be putting all of your entities into the same project.

If you have them in separate projects and you want to prevent circular project referencing you should do the mapping in a third project that references the first two.

Comment: I already do the mapping in a separate project that references the two. My problem is not with mapping. The problem is the need to I have a collection of ClassOne inside ClassTwo, that generates the circular reference. If you read the comment I gave to the question, it explains why I can't move all to one project.

Comment: If you have 2 separate projects for the classes you have in the example and you have a 3rd one for mapping, you should not have a circular reference. Or there is something you forgot to tell us.

Comment: There is circular reference because of these two lines:
public ClassTwo ClassTwo { get; set; }                      
public ICollection<ClassOne> ClassOnes { get; set;}    .Even the mapping being in a separate project

Comment: @GustavoAndrade How about create an iterface IClassOne on a 4th project, and make the 1st project references 4 and 2, 2nd references 4th and 3 references 1 and 2 ?

Comment: @Zaboda, that might work but I didn't want to do that. I really regret using entity framework instead of nhibernate in this project, it's just giving me headaches